# Activate/Deactivate Hyperlinks

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first go at asking a question so apologies to all if I haven't given enough info or messed up in some other way!

I have a sheet with areas which are hidden until required by the user. These are called for with a button and another button to hide them all again when creating a new workbook. The hidden areas each contain a hyperlink (these take the user to other sheets in the workbook) in a text box (this allows the hyperlink to work when the sheet is protected). My problem is that the hyperlinks are still active and the cursor shows a hand when over these hyperlinks even when they are hidden. How can I deactivate a hyperlink while it is hidden using VBA or a macro? Any assistance will be very welcome. Thanks

The sections on the sheet are hidden/shown by code which changes the color to the same as the background I didn't want to close columns or rows as I wanted to maintain the header and size of the sheet.

All the coding works for what I have done but have spent a long time trying to find an answer to my question without success. The hidden sections are up to 12 blocks of data entry cells which will be used dependant on the users project requirements.

A sections of the code I have placed below are for making block 12 appear and then next routine is for hiding all the blocks except number 1. The next is a sub routine that I have for hiding the text box of block number 2. I decided to change from having the hyperlink in a cell to a text box to allow the sheet to be protected but still use the hyperlinks for view only purposes. I have added the code for the routine for hiding the text box and it was this I was experimenting with to disable the hyperlink. However the only bit of code I could find that looked like it might do the job was EnableEvents but I couldn't achieve what I wanted with that, so here I am.

I'm sure you can see that I am note a programmer I borrow bits of code and stick them together and play with it until it works but I've run out of bits to stick and time to play.

```
Sub AppearCompOp12()
'
' AppearCompOp12 Macro
'

'
    Range("ar22:bd28").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Range("AR22").Select
    Selection.Font.Size = 16
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = -65536
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub

Sub ResetCapMSADashboard()
'
' ResetCapMSADashboard Macro
'

'
    Range( _
        "P6:AB12,AD6:AP12,AR6:BD12,AR14:BD20,AR22:BD28,AD14:AP20,AD22:AP28,P14:AB20,B14:N20,B22:N28,P22:AB28" _
        ).Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    End With
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ThemeColor = 1
        .TintAndShade = -0.14996795556505
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ThemeColor = 1
        .TintAndShade = -0.14996795556505
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ThemeColor = 1
        .TintAndShade = -0.14996795556505
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ThemeColor = 1
        .TintAndShade = -0.14996795556505
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ThemeColor = 1
        .TintAndShade = -0.14996795556505
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ThemeColor = 1
        .TintAndShade = -0.14996795556505
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Range("BG2:BG26").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("J7").Select

End Sub

Sub RecolourTB2()
'
' Change text box & text to background colourbox

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 9")).Select

    With Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Range("P10:W10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 9")).Select
    EnableEvents = False
    With Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill

        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.150000006
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Range("P9:W9").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: If I add a hyperlink to a cell and then hide the column that cells resides in, I don't get a hand appearing. You say the hyperlink is in a text box? How is the text box hidden? Also, welcome to SO... it is customary to include your first coding/formula attempts at this to show your research effort and avoid closure on grounds of too broad.

Comment: Please show us [what you have tried](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @divindunk: Welcome to Stack Overflow: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question and be sure to ask a [good, clear, concise question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion),  include the code, expected  behaviour, and what is wrong... then we can try to help

Comment: @divindunk: I Downvoted/voted to close because you didn't include a [MCVE] , it looks like [no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), and it looks like [no research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) was done.

Comment: I've edited my question hope I have got it right this time